# Measuring time for sorting 1 million floating point between 0 and 1 by sort in algorithm library

Tags: c++, windows, algorithm

I am doing some measurements on the speeds of sorting and was measuring the time taken to sort 1 million floating point values, all between [0,1] by using the standard std::sort in `<algorithm>.` On my hardware, intel core i5 with 6 GB Ram, the below code shows me that it takes approximately 1164.188 milliseconds. However, I doubt the correctness of this and want to ask if this measurement is correct. Please see the below code to know how I got 1164.188ms

```
#include<algorithm>
#include<iostream>
#include<windows.h>
using namespace std;
void main(){

    const int N = 1000000;
    FILE *f;
    f = fopen("invertedList.txt","r");
    if( f == NULL){
            printf("File not found\n");
            system("pause");
            exit(1);
    }
    int count = 0 ;
      //read input from a file
    float* a = (float*)malloc(N * sizeof(float));
    for( int i =0 ; i < N ; i++){

        fscanf(f, "%f,", &a[count]);

        count++;
    }
    fclose(f);
      //start the clock
    __int64 ctr1 = 0 , ctr2 = 0 , freq = 0 ;
    QueryPerformanceFrequency((LARGE_INTEGER *) &freq);
    QueryPerformanceCounter((LARGE_INTEGER *) &ctr1);

    sort(a,a+N);

    QueryPerformanceCounter((LARGE_INTEGER *)&ctr2);//stop clock
    double ans = ((ctr2 - ctr1) * 1.0 / freq);
    printf("The time elapsed in milliseconds is %f\n",(ans*1000));

    FILE *tow;
    tow = fopen("writesort.txt","w");
    for(int i =0 ; i< N;i++){
        fprintf(tow,"%f,",a[i]);
    }
    free(a);
    fclose(tow);
    getchar();



}
```

Comment: Why do you think this is wrong?

Comment: What implementation of `sort()` is that?  It is not any standard library--perhaps it is Windows specific?  How does it know how to compare elements?

Comment: @wallyk Introsort is very common nowadays. Or the very least a depth aware method. And the comparison is templated. Here <.

Comment: @templatetypedef: I read this paper : http://www.cse.chalmers.se/research/group/dcs/TechReports/gpuqsort.pdf in which the authors say that it took only 100ms to sort 1 million values. Not sure if they were talking about integers or some special case so wanted to check

Comment: To measure something, you'll *always* want a loop, with about 1M iterations that tests your code (the timing should be inside and saved).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would add a check to the return value of `fscanf(f, "%f,", &a[count]);` to be sure it read and converted a value.

The timing logic appears sound.  Note that it is measuring elapsed time.  As for accurately measuring the algorithm, that would only be true if the machine is lightly loaded or less.  Multiple runs can give an indication of the timing validity:  if close, then they are likely accurate.  If there are large variations (> 25%), then other system operations are disrupting the computation.

Comment: Can you please run this on your machine and tell me if you get the same or similar results

Comment: @Programmer:  I don't have windows, only Linux.

Comment: Last question before i accept ur answer. To check for return val of fscanf we just have to do int val = fscanf(); if(val==EOF) throw error?

Comment: @Programmer:  I would check whether it returns one, indicating that one value was converted.  If the format specified two conversions, scanf returns 2 on success.