# what to choose when dealing with large sequence of input

Tags: algorithm, sorting, data-structures, hashtable

I recently stumbled on a question

how to find the intersection of two sequence when each sequence can have duplicate numbers and the size is fairly big (close to one million) and the data type dealt with is Long.

I thought about sorting and finding intersection which is not a viable solution
I even thought about hash table it does not work as the space consideration has to be optimum

can someone suggest what would be the better way to handle it?

Thanks for reading the post

Comment: being @linuxdeveloper then gnu sort can work if you have enough disk space. You can then do the intersection of sorted sequences which you state you can do.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The question claims that “sorting and finding intersection ... is not a viable solution”.  However, from the standpoint of ease and clarity of coding, sorting is among the best solutions.  For any one-off problem, spending 10 minutes writing a sorting solution is more reasonable than spending 15 minutes writing a hashing solution, or half an hour writing a special tree program.

Sorting a million doubles with the python code shown below takes about 1.3 seconds on my old PC (AMD Athlon 5000, about 2GHz) and probably can be done four to five times faster than that on current processors.  Sorting two arrays in time O(n lg n) and then looking for matches in time O(n), as required for the question, might take a second or two on a modern PC.

```
In [237]: import random

In [238]: v = [random.random() for i in range(1000000)]

In [239]: %time u = sorted(v)
CPU times: user 1.32 s, sys: 0.00 s, total: 1.32 s
Wall time: 1.33 s
```

Note, [question #8630965](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8630965/measuring-time-for-sorting-1-million-floating-point-between-0-and-1-by-sort-in-a) refers to sorting a million floating point values in 1.168 seconds.

Answer (score 1):

Assume a long is a fixed size, say 64 bits. Plan for a partial binary tree of depth maximum 64. For each number in the first sequence, you're going to grow the tree. All leaves appear at depth 64. Each leaf has two integers which are counters referencing the two sequences.

```
for each number n in the first list
    current_node = root
    for i ranging from 1 to 64
        if the i-th bit of n is zero
            grow/traverse edge labeled 'zero' from current_node
        else
            grow/traverse edge labeled 'one' from current_node
        set current_node to be at end of this edge
    if the current_node (now at depth 64) is brand new
        set the node's first counter to 1; second counter to zero
    else
        increment current_node's first counter by 1
```

The second part of this is to process the second list, but update the second counter instead. You can also skip creating new nodes if you want because there won't be any intersection there. Then traverse the entire tree and see where both counters are non-zero.

Answer (score 1):

I think a hash table with 2M entries per list (so the hash table load stays reasonably low, at 50% or lower) is a good option. Fast, not prohibitively big, just 2M*4B (your longs are 4-byte long, right?) if you use the simplest implementation.

A sorted/search tree will be more compact than the hash table if there are few unique values in the list, but it will be bigger than the hash table if there are a lot of unique numbers (you need child/parent pointers in the tree nodes, and that's the overhead).

What's the statistics?

Answer (score 0):

To me, the problem boils down to:

- represent the *sparse* first input using some data structure
- traverse it with the second input as a key into the data structure computed in prior step.

My initial thought was a hash table as well. But we will need one node for each number.
Another author already has this idea.

My second thought was a B+ tree. We could map a sparse set using this tree. The leaf can contain a range of nos...that way, we can burn more cpu to search the leaf when looking for an intersection with the second input set. You do pay the cost of the b+ tree index in the interior nodes. Assuming that we do not store duplicates in the tree...no need for intersection. We can optimize the leaf with bit based storage to cut down on the space.